# How do I know how many CAL (Client Access Licenses) we have?

Tags: exchange, licensing

A former employee at our company bought a number of Exchange [CALs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_Access_License) for outlook. We can no longer get a hold of that former employee and we want to make sure we have enough. We are pretty sure we need to buy more but we don't know if we need 10 or 50 more. The Owner is afraid to contact Microsoft about it fearing that if we are using more than we have bought we may get penalized. The owner doesn't want to get cute, he wants to resolve the situation and buy exactly how many CALs we need without buying any extra. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 5):

- The owner should not be afraid. Contact microsoft directly. They are very reasonable in cases like that.
- The owwner should know. Well, not he, but if the COMPANY bought them, the company PAID for them. I would be more afraid of the tax office if I would not be able to figure out what I spend my money on. Note that financial documents must be kept more than 10 years in most jurisdictions ;) He should ask his accountant.

Answer (score 0):

You know how many you have by reviewing the license certificates that you get when you purchase them.  You can't check your CAL's other than having the physical paper certificates.  If you don't have those then there's really no way to prove that you bought them.

I concur with TomTom on the contacting Microsoft bit.  If you show them that you're honestly trying to comply with licensing they'll work with you.  Better that then to sit there fretting over it and knowing that you're not compliant.